# What can I do to get this function to output?

Tags: php

What do I need to do to get output from this function?

```
<?php
function recursion($a)
{
    if ($a < 20) {
    echo "$a";
    recursion($a + 1);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Because variable `$an` is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do I need to do to get output from this function?

Just call the function:

```
function recursion($a)
{
    if ($a < 20) {
        echo "$a";
        recursion($a + 1);
    }
}

recursion(1); // <--- here
```

Defining a function only *defines* it, not execute it.  To execute a function you have to call it.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: Before downvoting, please note that my answer was according to the original question. The question was edited after my answer, making my answer to appear irrelevant.**

Possibly you want to write a function that outputs all numbers from given number (passed as an argument) through 19 (ie < 20). To do that you have to write:

```
echo $a;
```

and not:

```
echo "$an";
```

`$an` is not defined. If you want to print the output in newline, you can write:

```
echo $a, "\n";
```

There are some other ways also for printing newline. However `'\n'` will not work as single quote does not identifies newline escape character.

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to say "$a\n"

Comment: @JaySSetano edited my answer for more explanation and minor correction. If it solves your problem, please accept the answer.